# Git - how to push on every repository inside folder

Tags: git, ubuntu, terminal, push

On my local computer I have every project inside my workspace folder, there I have some git repositories which are cloned from repositories of github, bitbucket, etc.

So for example I have something like this:

```
workspace\
    githubrepo1\
    githubrepo2\
    bitbucketrepo1\
    bitbucketrepo2\
    ...
```

There could be many more (of course they are not their folder names).

I have done some commits on some of my local repositories and now I want to push them to their respective remote repositories. The remote directions are configured correctly and I am using ssh access, so they won't ask me for password.

Maybe this could be done with some terminal command, but I don't know how. I am using Ubuntu.

So, how to make a `git push` on every repository inside `workspace`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple shell construct:

```
for repo in ${HOME}/workspace/*
do
  (cd ${repo} && git push)
done
```

If you do it often, add this to your `.bashrc`

```
pushall()
{ for repo in .......
  ........
  done
}
```

Then you can just run `pushall` whenever you need to...

Answer (score 0):

use repo command :

```
repo upload
```

Comment: Isn't this only for android?, can you explain more?